# start_thread clone taking most of the time in parallel program - bad parallelization or wrong report?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, intel-vtune

I'm currently working on parallelizing a C++ program in order to improve its performance on multi-core systems. Using OpenMP and considering the challenges (thread synchronization, data accesses, etc) we finally found a way to make the entire program parallel, but the performance improvement is not overwhelming.

Using Intel VTune Amplifier, I did a hotspot search and found out that in almost every function call that should be done in parallel, "start_thread clone" from libgomp.so is taking more time than the actual execution of the function:

[Intel VTune Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWWIP.png)

This is really unexpected, since I checked that, on current OpenMP implementations, there should be almost no penalty for switching from parallel and serial regions. According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132565/how-do-i-ask-openmp-to-create-threads-only-once-at-each-run-of-the-program):

> The thread are started when your program starts ( or the first time are needed, 
>   depending on the implementation ). Pause your program anywhere else, and you'll 
>   notice the threads are still there

I did this, stopped the program in the debugger, before the first parallel region there was only one thread, afterwards, wherever I stopped (parallel or serial region), there were multiple threads. So I was convinced that there should be no overhead from "respawing" new threads each time.

Now VTune tells me differently, as far as I can understand the measurements. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Do you switch debug info ON for all your user modules (using -g)? And is this possible for you to use Intel OpenMP implementation?  Ideally you need to do both things in order to make parallel program profiling in VTune most meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Please download corresponding debug package for libgomp containing debug symbols for this library - VTune will be able to classify CPU time better. Presence of libgomp in a hotspot may be caused by Spin Locks as result of bad work splitting.

Also please note that time on screenshot does not mean "start_thread clone" took 11 seconds - it means hotspot (unresolved function) took 11 seconds being called from start_thread through calcGrowthStep region.